# html is not getting rendered after web-view finishes content loading

Tags: html, ios, webview

I have to render html into web-view, In some cases it renders nothing on webview when 
-invalid html received from server or html contains flash,.swf and other unsuported media types for iOS.

Webview's `webViewDidFinishLoad` is getting called in this case also, so I am unable to get this using webview's delegate methods.

To detect these cases I am taking points colors on webview diagonally and when I get alpha 1, it means html render successfully else its a blank.
I am using [UIView+ColorOfPoint](https://github.com/ivanzoid/ikit/tree/master/UIView+ColorOfPoint) for getting color at point.

Is there any best way to achieve the same. Please help if you any any better solution.

Thanks

Comment: Did `didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` get called?

Comment: No webViewDidFinishLoad is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement following code.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     [webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error] baseURL:nil];

     if (error)
     {
         // implement your code.
     }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented it but didFinishLoad calls and nothing displayed on webview and to detect such cases I am using this trick. But if this can be achieve in a better way please guide.